# Mysterious Error in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger-2.0

I'm using composition to solve a problem with my data types, and I'm getting the strangest error I've ever seen in Swagger. It doesn't even have a line number, although I've narrowed it down to a small block of code.

The error I get says this:

```
Resolver error
e is undefined
```

The simplest way to get rid of it is the comment out the Sponsor definition. Actually, I only need to comment out the last element of Sponser, which is the four lines that define the Partners element. I can also get rid of it by commenting out the two lines that follow `Partner:`. And I can get rid of it by removing the Contests element from the Event type.

Here's what I think is going on. Event is my base type, and includes an array of type Contest. But all the other types, including Contest, include allOf Event. Furthermore, Sponsor includes an array of Partner, which (since it includes Event) includes the array of Contest. I think that's where Swagger is getting confused. Sponsor has its own array of Contests, and it included and array of Partners, each of which has its own array of Contests, too. And Contest has its own array of Contests. (Yes, this is consistent with the customer's data design.) Any of the edits I described either remove the two levels of objects with an array of Contests.

Has anybody else seen anything like this, and is there anything I can do about it? Or is this just a bug in Swagger?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: RESTful API to retrieve Titles Metadata
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Mystery

host: localhost:8080
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /event:
    get:
      operationId: getEvent
      summary: searches names
      description: |
        Search by names, across all types, or by a specific type.
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: title
        description: name to search for
        required: true
        type: string
      - in: query
        name: start
        required: false
        type: boolean
      - in: query
        name: type
        required: false
        type: string
        description: |
          May be "contest", "partner", "sponsor", or "dancer". If missing, will search for all types.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results
# I also don't know why I need to comment these out.
          # content:
          #   application/json:
          #     schema:
          #       type: array
          #       items:
          #         $ref: '#/definitions/Event'
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
definitions:
  Event:
    type: object
    properties:
      eventType:
        type: string
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name:
        type: string
      description:
        type: string
      contests:
        type: array
        items: 
          $ref: '#/definitions/Contest'
    required:
    - id
    - name
    - description
    - contests
    - eventType
  Contest:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Event'
    - type: object
      properties:
        parentEvent:
          type: string
        venue:
          type: string
      required:
      - parentEvent
      - venue
  Dancer:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Event'
    - type: object
      properties:
        eventInvitationDate:
          type: string
          format: date
        venue:
          type: string
      required:
      - eventInvitationDate
      - venue
  Sponsor:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Event'
    - type: object
      properties:
        invitationDate:
          type: string
          format: date
        parentEvent:
          type: string
        # commenting out these four lines makes the error go away.
        partners:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Partner'
  Partner:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Event'
    type: object
    properties:
      invitationDate:
        type: string
        format: date
      parentEvent:
        type: string
      venue:
        type: string
    required:
    - invitationDate
    - parentEvent
    - venue
# two problems:
# 1. Schema error at definitions['Event'].discriminator
#    should be string on line 84 (discriminator:)
# 2. Resolver error:
#    e is undefined
#    (no line number)
```

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI / Swagger Editor do you use?

Comment: I had to reload the browser in my case to get rid of the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Resolver error: e is undefined" is a [bug in Swagger UI 3.x](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3051) which is caused by circular references in `definitions` – e.g. `Event` refers to `Contest` which refers to `Event`.

> ```
> # I also don't know why I need to comment these out.
>       # content:
>       #   application/json:
>       #     schema:
>       #       type: array
>       #       items:
>       #         $ref: '#/definitions/Event'
> ```

The `content` keyword is not used in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, it was introduced in OpenAPI 3.0. In OpenAPI 2.0 you specify the response media type and `schema` like this:

```yaml
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results
          schema:
            type: array
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope that, if they're not going to fix this soon, they at least change the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Just refresh your page to resolve this mysterious error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you're editing in https://editor-next.swagger.io/ refreshing the page clears the error for me.

Comment: Did it for me too!

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused due to redundant spaces.Remove all redundant spaces and check.